# How to execute multiple class instance in Python with Argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

My project has several categories with multiple scripts inside, each script allows you to perform a unique task.

To run my project, I give my main.py arguments that I retrieve with argparse.

Example: `./main.py --category web --script S1_HTTP_HEADER --url https://qwerty.com --port 1234`

However, I need to create an argument to run all my scripts at once.

Example : `./main.py --category web --all --url https://qwerty.com --port 1234`

Actually, my main.py looks like this :

```
if args.category == "web":
    if args.script == 'S1_HTTP_HEADER':
        from scripts.WEB_S1_HTTPHEADER import RequestHeader
        make_request = RequestHeader(args.url, args.port)
        make_request.insert_value()
```

Do you have solutions to run all scripts at once with only one argument?

For information, each script has a class that I have to instantiate with a URL and a PORT. Of course I have to import my class in my main.py before the operation.

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

I would define a custom parsing action to load all callables respective to the category.

That class defines a mapping binding both categories and associated callables.
Each callable is a tuple composed of the script name and the associated callable object.
An additional argument "scripts" is created by the custom action as a list object. Empty by default.

Import mechanism needs to be changed a little too.

```
from scripts import WEB_S1_HTTPHEADER, WEB_S2_HTTPHEADER, WEB_S3_HTTPHEADER

class GetScripts(argparse.Action):
    """
    """
    SCRIPTS = {"web": [("S1_HTTPHEADER", WEB_S1_HTTPHEADER.RequestHeader), ("S2_HTTPHEADER", WEB_S2_HTTPHEADER.RequestHeader), ("S3_HTTPHEADER", WEB_S3_HTTPHEADER.RequestHeader)]}

    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kwargs):
        super(GetScripts, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parsobj, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
        if values:
            category = getattr(namespace, "category")
            setattr(namespace, "scripts", self.SCRIPTS.get(category, []))
```

Define the keyword argument "--all" associated to the custom action:

```
your_parser.add_argument("--all", nargs="?", default=False, const=True, action=GetScripts)
```

You can then iterate over the "scripts" argument to run each configured callable.

main.py now looks like:

```
if args.all:
    for _, func in args.scripts:
        make_request = func(args.url, args.port)
        make_request.insert_value()
```

A new category or a new script means however changing the class member SCRIPTS.

Does it answer to your need?